# python3: warnings.warn() crashes on bytes object after numpy import

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm looking for an explanation (and ideally also a workaround) for a really weird numpy importing problem. Here is a minimal code example: Reproducible for both python3.3 and python3.2, numpy-v1.8.0 and today's numpy snapshot from github.

```
from warnings import warn
warn(b"please be careful!")
```

Output:

```
test.py:2: UserWarning: b'please be careful!'
warn(b"please be careful!")
```

Now with numpy import:

```
from warnings import warn
import numpy
warn(b"please be careful!")
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 3, in <module>
    warn(b"please be careful!")
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy installs a warnings filter, and such filters are matched against warning text with a regular expression.

The fact that your initial warning with a `bytes` object *worked* was just a coincidence, the API only supports *string* warnings. That you see the exception is not the fault of Numpy, **any** warnings filter with a message component will trigger it:

```
>>> import warnings
>>> warnings.warn(b'careful!')
__main__:1: UserWarning: b'careful!'
>>> warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message='foo bar')
>>> warnings.warn(b'Do be careful!')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

The work-around is to use the API as designed, with *string warnings* (or instances of the [`Warning` exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#Warning)), not `bytes` objects.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So the general idea is that the warnings.warn() function should not have been called with a bytes object in the first place?

Comment: @cel: exactly. `message` must be a string or instance of (a subclass of) the `Warnings` exception. Anything else is not supported; if it happens to work when no filters have been installed then that's a coincidence.